# How can I add the image using sd card image path and apply it on the profile picture image?

Tags: java, android

I have created the following navigation drawer layout but now I want to apply the sd card image on profile picture view. How can I apply it?

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: you have to make click event on profile pic, then set image from gallery action, at time you have to store image in sharedpreferences with base64 string, now you have to check if image avaible in sharedpreferences then show other wise set from gallery

Answer (score 0):

1) Read your image from the sd card:

```
File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "path_to_your_file");

if(image.exists())
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());
```

2) Set it into your appropriate `ImageView`

```
ImageView imgProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id);
imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Is is giving me another problem this method overlapping the all images which is in listview

Comment: please post your adapter code and how you set those icons

Comment: public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon, boolean isCounterVisible,
   String count) {
  this.title = title;
  this.icon = icon;
  this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
  this.count = count;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
  return this.title;
 }

 public int getIcon() {
  return this.icon;
 }

Comment: Here icon the icons for friend circle, setting logout etc that I am fetching from drawable folder but now I want to fetch the profile picture from gallery and it is giving me corrent image path but it is not going to appy on profile pic cause icon type is int and my gallery image path is in string form. What will be the solution for this problem???

Comment: @PankajLagad you can add an another constructor for `NavDrawerItem` that takes a `String` as parameter and use it for the header item only

Comment: Thanks bro... Your solution is work for me... You have saved my lot of time...Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting Image from sdcard

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
    ImageView img;
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

  //add permission AndroidManifest
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```